# How do all the unknown users end up on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, openid, gravatar

In particular, several users all have the same gravatar. Yet the have different reputation scores, etc.

I thought the gravatar was an MD5 hash of the users email address. Thus I don't get how there can be all these duplicates?

[image] [unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93535/unknown),[unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118689/unknown),[unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121040/unknown),[unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122365/unknown),[unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122596/unknown),

Just curious...

Comment: Nice gravatar, by the way.

Comment: thanks Bill - its borrowed and tweaked with respect from Geico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic gravatars are generated from the user's IP address, not their email address.

Comment: Do all the users come from the same IP? If so, why aren't they merged?

Comment: They aren't necessarily the same person.  If you and I work at the same company, or just have the same ISP, we're going to appear to have the same IP address from across the Internet.

Comment: ...but, yes, I did check, and all of those users do have the same IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I merged all these users since they are clearly the same entity.

In the future, you can just flag any post by this user for mod attention and let us know -- unless you want it to be a discussion topic in and of itself here on meta.

Probably not a bad idea in this case to have the discussion; we do reserve the right to merge accounts that are obvious duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing keeps two people from having the same nickname.

Comment: but the nickname is not the source of the gravatar :)